# Detecting a cycle and making the summation faster

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, cycle

Let's assume that we're given an array of positive integers, probably of a very large size, and we're given another positive integer, and let's call it k, and another positive integer, which we will call n.

We add the integers while the sum does not exceed k, and we repeat the process from where we're left off (if we reach the end of the array, we go back to the first), and we continue this process.

For instance, if array is

```
a[5]={1, 3, 5, 7, 4}
```

and k, n are

```
k=9, n=6
```

then 6 processes we go through would be

```
 (1, 3, 5), (7), (4, 1, 3), (5), (7), (4, 1, 3)
```

and the sum would be 9+7+8+5+7+8 = 44
and the following code suffices (realsum would be the sum)

```
     int g=0;
     int realsum=0;
     while(g < n){
                sum=0;
                while(sum + a[g]<= k){
                sum=sum+a[g];
                pointer=pointer+1;
                if(pointer >=5){
                    pointer=pointer%5; 
                }
               }
               realsum=realsum+sum;
            g++;

        }
```

5 can be replaced by the size of the array.

Anyways, if n is really large, we could take advantage of the fact that there's a cycle 
(7), (4, 1, 3), (5), that's going to be repeated over and over, and it will really make the sum calculation much faster. I was wondering if there's a good way of detecting such cycles in the array and apply that to this example in C++. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can maintain an array that stores the sum at any index and the next index for the sequence in the array for given k value. First check if the index has calculated value and if not calculate & store it. If the sum has already been calculated use it and jump to the next index defined in the array. Something like this:

```
int a[5]={1, 3, 5, 7, 4};
std::pair<int, int> sums[5];
memset(sums, 0, sizeof(sums));
int g=0, pointer=0, n=6, k=9;
int realsum=0;
while(g<n)
{
  int sum=sums[pointer].first;
  if(!sum)
  {
    int ref_pointer=pointer;
    while(sum+a[pointer]<=k)
    {
      sum+=a[pointer];
      if(++pointer==5)
        pointer=0;
    }
    sums[ref_pointer].first=sum;
    sums[ref_pointer].second=pointer;
  }
  else
    pointer=sums[pointer].second;
  realsum+=sum;
  g++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First you could storage every solved process using the index (`start` and `end`).

You need to have two containers that would storage:

- The processes solved, storage in the same order as solved (for example: `std::vector<std::pair<unsigned int, unsigned int>>`). Where `std::pair<unsigned int, unsigned int>` is the range of the process solved.
- The processes solved, storage sorted by `start index` and `end index` (for example: `std::set<std::pair<unsigned int, unsigned int>&>`). Where `std::pair<unsigned int, unsigned int>&` reference to the same range in the first container.

When you solve a process you search for existence in the second container if it's there, you found a cycle and using the second container can reconstructed if it's not there insert the range in the two containers.

A better match for the data structure proposed is [`boost::multi_index`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/multi_index/), that let you search by multiple index. In this case would be the range `(start, end)` of the process and the order in what was found.

Answer (score 0):

If at any moment in the process you hit the same "separation" point that you hit before, it immediately means that from that point on you will be repeating the previously made separations again and again all the way to the end. This is what you have to detect.

If the size of the array in `N` (`N = 5` in your example), then you can use an additional array of boolean flags of size `N`, in which you will mark all elements at which you started to build the next piece. Once you discover that you start a new piece from the same element for the second time, you will immediately know that the rest of the procedure is a repeating cycle.

In your example, you will mark values `1`, `7`, `4`, `5` and then you will attempt to mark `7` again. That way you will discover that at value `7` your algorithm begins to discover a repetitive separation pattern: `(7), (4, 1, 3), (5), (7), (4, 1, 3), (5), (7), (4, 1, 3), (5) ...`

The rest is just a question of calculating the final result without continuing the iterations. You can, for example, continue the procedure after detecting the beginning of the cycle. But now you will count how many pieces are in the cycle. Let's say there are `P` pieces (`P = 3` in your example). In the remaining number of pieces to find (let's call it `n'`) is greater than `P` then you can immediately add `S * (n' / P)` (where `S` is the sum of all elements in the array) to the final sum - that's the contribution the full cycles will make.

After that you only have to find the remaining `n''` pieces - the last, generally incomplete "cycle" - and add them to the final sum.

One can probably implement it more cleverly, store some additional information about the already found pieces, and thus avoid continuing the procedure after the cycle is detected.